# How do I turn off account creation?

Tags: 7, users

Recently I've been receiving many spammers creating an account on my website, which is quite basic and for which I don't need users create an account.

What would the likely URL that spam bots are finding be?
Is there a way to turn off account?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The answer given on [How do I remove the user registration/login form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352381/how-do-i-remove-the-user-registration-login-form) is relevant for this question too.

> While it's technically possible to remove the login functionality, you shouldn't, because then your administrator could never log onto the site.
>
> In order to remove the register functionality, you simply need to browse to admin/user/settings (for Drupal 6) or admin/config/people/accounts (for Drupal 7 and 8) and select the the "Only site administrators can create new user accounts" option.

Comment: You also need to clear the cache for it to take affect.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the forms all together. In a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
    case 'user_register_form':
      $form['#access'] = FALSE;
    break;
  }
}
```

Depending on your needs, you can either create a custom page and set the login block there, so you and other administrators can login, or install [HybridAuth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module to allow visitors to login and register new accounts only through social media 3rd parties.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional step to the above you could change the default url path from /user login screen using "rename admin paths" module to something nobody would guess.

Eg, www.sitename/randomcombition/ < this way user's will have to know this url before they can even try logging in.

Comment: Not sure how useful URL obfuscation really is

Answer (score 0):

1. yourwebsite.com/user - this is the standard Drupal login URL (at least for 7) and bots find it routinely.
2. Remove visitor registration as described in Chapabu's answer